# Get only a number of the following or preceding siblings in XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I wonder if anyone knows how to get a specified amount of elements for following-siblings or preceding-siblings functions in XPath and XSLT (e.g. I only need 2 elements of the following siblings of the current element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an expression of the following form:

```
/<path_to_element>/following-sibling::*[(position() - 1) < $n]
```

For example, to get the 3 siblings following `<c/>` in the following document:

```
<test>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <d/>
    <e/>
    <f/>
    <g/>
</test>
```

Use the following expression:

```
/*/c/following-sibling::*[(position() - 1) < 3]
```